# Issue with Matplotlib funcanimation when called from a Slider on changed event

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to show the sampling process of different statistical distributions. To this end, I want to use the animation library from matplotlib combined with the Slider object to allow the user to select the parameters of the distribution before launching the animation.

I'm creating a subplot containing four axes objects (each one is gonna show a different distribution). I first take samples from the four distributions and plot the result as an histogram on each axis object.

I'm then creating 2 Slider objects that represent the mean and the standard deviation of the distribution. To make them interactive, I connect them via a function that holds the call to the FuncAnimation object.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ((ax1,ax2), (ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2)
axes = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]

n = 50
normal = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size= n)
uniform = np.random.random(size=n)
chi_square = np.random.chisquare(2,n) # degree 2
gamma = np.random.gamma(2, size=n)
distributions = [normal, uniform, chi_square, gamma]
distributions_names= ["Normal", "Uniform", "Chi Square", "Gamma"]
color = ["red", "green", "blue", "purple"]

for i,ax in enumerate(axes):

    ax.hist(distributions[i], color = color[i], alpha=0.5)
    ax.set_title("{} distribution".format(distributions_names[i]))


# creation of the sliders object

axcolor = 'white'
pos_ax1 = ax1.get_position()
axmean = plt.axes([pos_ax1.x0, 0.5, pos_ax1.x1 - pos_ax1.x0, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor) # add axes to current figure
axvar = plt.axes([pos_ax1.x0, 0.45, pos_ax1.x1 - pos_ax1.x0, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

smean = Slider(axmean, "Mean", -2,2, valinit=0.0, color=color[0], alpha= 0.5)
svar = Slider(axvar, "STD", 0,4, valinit=1.0, color=color[0], alpha= 0.5)

def custom(current_frame, axis, distribution, name):

    if current_frame == n:
        a.event_source.stop()

    axis.cla()
    axis.hist(distribution[:current_frame], color=color[0], alpha=0.5)
    #axis.set_xlim([-6,6])
    axis.set_title("{} distribution".format(name))

def update_normal(val):

    normal = np.random.normal(loc=smean.val, scale=svar.val, size= n)
    a = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), custom, fargs=(ax1,normal,"normal"), interval=25) #interval is the frame rate in ms


smean.on_changed(update_normal) # call func with the new slider value
svar.on_changed(update_normal)
```

I would expect that when the slider is moved, an animation starts showing the sampling process (the code is being done only for the normal distribution at the moment). However, at the moment nothing happens when the Slider is being moved.

I would add that I managed to replot the distribution (without animation) when only working with the Slider object.

After looking on StackOverflow, I've seen some suggestion that a reference should be kept to the animation object, otherwise the animation stops running, so I've tried to add

```py
return a
```

At the end of the function "update_normal" but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You can create a global variable `global a` and assign to it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment but if I understood properly, it didn't solve my problem. I predifined a variable a in the following manner: 

global a 

and then assign the return of the animation.FuncAnimation  call to it: 

a = animation.FuncAnimation(...)

But this didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you need to retain a reference to the animation instance for it not to be garbage collected.

In this case you can either

#### use global

```
a = None

def update_normal(val):
    global a
    a = FuncAnimation(...)
```

or

#### use a mutable object

```
a = [None]

def update_normal(val):

    a[0] = FuncAnimation(...)
```