# Generating repeatedly updating graph (FuncAnimation - Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a code that will generate a graph that is being repeatedly updated and has twin axes (2 y-axis, sharing the same x-axis).

The code works well when I don't combine it with FuncAnimation, however when I try to do that I get an empty graph.

```
def animate(i):
    data=prices(a,b,c)    #function that gives a DataFrame with 2 columns and index
    plt.cla()   
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(data.index, data.value1)
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(data.index, data.value2)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()     
    plt.tight_layout()  

call = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, 1000)  
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show
'''


I believe the error is in "call". Unfortunately, I don't know FuncAnimation so well.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def getPrices(i):
    return pd.DataFrame(index=[datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(10)], data={'value1':range(10), 'value2':[(x + i) % 5 for x in range(10)]})

def doAnimation():
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    def animate(i):
        #data=prices(a,b,c)    #function that gives a DataFrame with 2 columns and index
        data = getPrices(i)

        plt.cla()
        ax.plot(data.index, data.value1)
        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.plot(data.index, data.value2)
        plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()     
        plt.tight_layout()  
        return ax, ax2

    call = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, 1000)  
    plt.show()

doAnimation()
```

**UPDATE**:

Though this works in my environment, OP in a comment indicated it doesn't work and the following  warning is raised:

> UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. anim, that exists until you have outputted the Animation using plt.show() or anim.save()

As `plt.show()` is called immediately after the call to `FuncAnimation()`, this is puzzling, but perhaps the following will help to ensure the `Animation` does not get deleted prematurely:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def getPrices(i):
    return pd.DataFrame(index=[datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(10)], data={'value1':range(10), 'value2':[(x + i) % 5 for x in range(10)]})

def doAnimation():
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    def animate(i):
        #data=prices(a,b,c)    #function that gives a DataFrame with 2 columns and index
        data = getPrices(i)

        plt.cla()
        ax.plot(data.index, data.value1)
        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.plot(data.index, data.value2)
        plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()     
        plt.tight_layout()  
        return ax, ax2

    call = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, 1000)  
    return call

callSave = doAnimation()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get the following error:

UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you have outputted the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.
  warnings.warn(

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Try putting a line like `call = None` at global scope (right after the imports), so that `call` doesn't get deleted when `doAnimation()` returns, and see if that helps.

Comment: It kind of works now. Sometimes when I run the code in Jupyter Notebook I get an empty graph, other times what I get is ok. I think the code is ok and the issue is on my side. Should I do something with my Anaconda (update, etc.)? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sounds like things are moving in the right direction. I'm not certain how to make it more reliable in your environment. Here are a couple of things you can try: (1) make `callSave` a global list with one element and assign return value of `FuncAnimation` to that element - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512722/18135454), and (2) experiment with the arguments for [`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) such as interval, cache_from_data, blit, etc.